# Como compilar arquivo C utilizando o Sublime Text no Windows 8.1 64 bit?

Tags: c, windows, compilação, sublime-text-2, software

Instalei o [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) no Windows 8.1 64 bit.

**Como compilar um arquivo *.c através do Sublime no Windows?**

É necessário instalar um compilador e/ou mais outro programa para alertar erros do código e criar o arquivo executável para eu poder testar o programa? Se sim, quais são os programas mais recomendados [leve; prático; estável]?

Comment: Sim, você vai precisar de um compilador C, mas vou deixar para outros te recomendarem um, já que quase não uso C nem Windows.

Comment: Pois é, no Linux compilo no terminal com o Clang, já no Windows imaginei que era necessário instalar mais coisa...

Comment: As pessoas que deram votos negativos a essa pergunta poderiam explicar por que ela é ruim? Na minha opinião ela segue o padrão do site.

Comment: Não entendi também Renan... Admito que não me esforcei muito antes de perguntar, mas logo depois até achei a solução e respondi abaixo

Answer (score 6):

**Resolvido**!!

Segui estas etapas contidas nesse link: http://www.ishaanrawat.com/building-running-c-in-sublime-text-windows/

1: Baixar a última versão do [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files)

2: Instalá-lo preferencialmente em **C:/MinGW**. Instalei os pacotes *mingw32-base* e o *mingw32-gcc-g++* (Não tenho certeza se é essencial instalar esses dois pacotes)

3: Localizar o caminho da pasta bin (**C:/MinGW/bin**)

4: Windows + F -> Configurações -> digite *ambiente sistema* -> Editar as variáveis de ambiente do sistema
ou
botão direito no Meu Computador -> Propriedades -> Sistema -> Avançado -> **Variáveis do ambiente**

5: Nas variáveis do usuário, clique em *Novo*. No nome coloque *MinGW*, já no valor coloque o caminho da pasta bin (terceiro passo), ex.: *C:\MinGW\bin*. Dê um Ok, depois OK novamente.

6: Abra o Sublime Text. Vá em *Tools* -> *Build System* -> *C++*

7: Ctrl + B para **compilar** e Ctrl + Shift + B para **executar**

OBS.: **salve todos os arquivos na pasta bin sem colocá-los numa pasta**. O caminho do arquivo deve ser nesse formato: C:/MinGW/bin/Arquivo.cpp

Deu certo! :D

Comment: O problema de usar MinGW é que ele não é necessariamente um compilador para Windows. Ele permite criar executáveis PE para Windows, mas somente a medida que você utilize apenas funções nativas do C ou de algumas poucas bibliotecas que foram trazidas do Linux. Você não pode usar, por exemplo, sockets, o que seria fundamental ter já que quase tudo desenvolvido hoje é orientado à Web. Um compilador mais adequado para desenvolver aplicações em C para Windows seria o Visual Studio, que possui sua versão gratuita [disponível aqui](http://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-express-vs).

Comment: Olá @webgykl, não se esqueça de colocar uma parte do conteúdo aqui (ou traduzí-lo inteiro para cá). Pode ser que a página fique offline e a resposta perca sua validade. Além disso, a solução está em inglês, então acaba não sendo de muita ajuda para futuros usuários que não são fluentes em inglês.

Comment: @Havenard, Por que eu não poderia utilizar a api de sockets do Windows com o MinGW?

Comment: Porque não tem.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal pode sim utilizar API de socket. O Windows possui uma camada que permite o uso dos recursos definidos pelo padrão POSIX. Veja mais: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463220.aspx
A grande maiora das coisas que você fazo com o Visual Studio, você faz com o MinGW. Uso MinGW no Windows a quase 10 anos e só precisei do Visual Studio quando precisei linkar com algumas bibliotecas em C++ que não haviam versões para o MinGW.